# Error when trying to insert many-to-many after saving new entity in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, dbcontext

The problem that I'm stuck on consists of the following steps. I hesitate which approach is the right one - I want to save a new entity, part of many-to-many relation. After saving it I want to update the table in which this entity is a foreign key forming a composite key.

I thought this could happen in 2 ways - by directly saving a record in the many-to-many table, or by adding it to the navigation property - a collection in the newly saved entity mentioned foremost.

I keep getting the following exception no matter what I try:

> The instance of entity type 'PartCar' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CarId', 'PartId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I expected the number of cars inserted to be equal to the dto array length and also I expected the junction table to be updated with the id of the car and each of the` ids of the partsId array. Apparently I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

```
public static string ImportCars(CarDealerContext context, string inputJson)
{
     CarDto[] dtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarDto[]>(inputJson);
     var parts = context.Parts.AsNoTracking().ToList();

     foreach(var  carDto in dtos) 
     {
         var newCar = new Car { Make = carDto.Make, Model = carDto.Model, TravelledDistance = carDto.TravelledDistance };

         context.Cars.Add(newCar);
         context.SaveChanges();

         foreach(var partId in carDto.PartCars)
         {
             if (parts.Any(p => p.Id == partId))
             {
                 var part = parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == partId);

                 newCar.PartCars.Add(new PartCar
                 {
                     PartId = partId,
                     CarId = newCar.Id
                 });
             }
             
             context.SaveChanges();
         }
     }

     return $"Successfully imported {dtos.Length}";
}
```

```
[
  {
    "make": "Opel",
    "model": "Omega",
    "travelledDistance": 176664996,
    "partsId": [
      38,
      102,
      23,
      116,
      46,
      68,
      88,
      104,
      71,
      32,
      114
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: post entity configurations, something might be wrong, as well as entities themself.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing obvious stands out, so you may have an issue with your mapping though the key referenced is the composite of the Car ID and Part ID so the most obvious thing I would check is that the Car ID is being set to a new value after SaveChanges(). (I.e. recognized as an Identity column for example)

However, I would point out that EF is designed to work with object graphs and handling relationships between entities. If the relationships are set up correctly, You don't need to be explicit with saving a Car then adding it's parts. Ideally within an operation with a DbContext you should only ever call `SaveChanges()` once.

```
public static string ImportCars(CarDealerContext context, string inputJson)
{
     CarDto[] dtos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarDto[]>(inputJson);
     var parts = context.Parts.ToList();

    foreach(var  carDto in dtos) 
    {
        var newCar = new Car 
        { 
            Make = carDto.Make, 
            Model = carDto.Model, 
            TravelledDistance = carDto.TravelledDistance 
        };

        foreach(var partId in carDto.PartCars)
        {
            var part = parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == partId);
            if(part == null)
                continue;
            newCar.PartCars.Add(new PartCar
            {
                Part = part,
            });
        }
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
    return $"Successfully imported {dtos.Length}";
}
```

Notice here when loading the parts we let EF track the instances, then when creating the PartCar, we just need to set the Part navigation property and add it to the Car's PartCars collection. EF will handle the rest including populating the Car FK and Part FK to build the composite key. Based on the relationships, EF will fill in FKs automatically and ensure that related entities are inserted in the correct order. This is generally advisable rather than working with FKs directly since it can be pretty easy to accidentally use an incorrect value in a FK when dealing with several similar references which might result in an error, or worse, an incorrect record assignment which would be silent. (A matching ID happens to exist in the incorrect table resulting in the wrong relationship being saved)

When dealing with references to parts, if the overall parts table is pretty small, doing:

```
var parts = context.Parts.ToList();
```

... is OK, but if you've got several thousand parts in the catalog and you're inserting a handful of cars with maybe a dozen common parts each then loading the entire Parts catalog can be costly. In this case you can streamline it:

```
var partIds = dtos.SelectMany(x => x.PartCars).Distinct.ToList();
var parts = context.Parts.Where(x => partIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

This would load all of the parts that are referenced in your passed in Car DTOs. So if your cars use just 20 parts out of a catalog of 3000 parts, the loaded parts entities would just be those 20 instead of all 3000.

If after these changes you are still getting an error on SaveChanges around unique constraint violations in the PartCars, then you might have an issue in the Car DTOs coming in where there is a duplicate part ID in the collection. This may be something you want to guard against in a method like this, where you filter out duplicate part IDs with a Distinct, or check for duplicates and log an issue where one was passed in before filtering it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply! I've been pretty stuck for the last days on this exercise. Also I feel as if anything going on in the ORM/ EF happens like magic. I don't know how it works and this is a little confusing. Thanks again!